# Not able to query standard user field 'StartDay' in salesforce

Tags: apex

I want to query start of day and end of day field from the user object but I am getting error for that refer images for more details[image]

Comment: Please include your code as *text*, not images. Images are *horrible* for accessibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both fields are not accessible through API. To get past this, you will need to create a custom formula field to pull in the data from the standard fields. You can then use the custom formula in your SOQL.

**StartDay Formula field**
Data Type - Text
Formula - TEXT(StartDay)

**EndDay Formula field**
Data Type - Text
Formula - TEXT(EndDay)

```
select StartDay__c from User
```